# Formatting output of foreach command

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell and I can't figure out how to format the output of this foreach loop oneliner.

```
foreach ($user in cat C:\list.txt) {Get-ADUser $user | select -Property             
GivenName,Surname,SamAccountName}

GivenName Surname    SamAccountName
--------- -------    --------------
Bob       Smith      SmithB
Fred      Williams   WilliamsF
Ann       Jones      JonesA
Joan      Scott      ScottJ
Eve       Wood       WoodE
George    Peters     PetersG
Alice     Watt       Watt
```

The C:\list.txt contains a list of the SamAccountName, one per line.

What I'm looking for is to have the output look like this:

```
Bob Smith SmithB; Fred Williams WilliamsF; Ann Jones JonesA; Joan Scott ScottJ; Eve Wood WoodE; George Peters PetersG; Alice Watt Watt
```

I would also like to avoid creating any new files in the process.

Comment: inside your foreach loop, save the user lookup results to a $Var [perhaps `$ADUser`], and then add a line that concatenates the values. something like `'{0} {1} {2}' -f $ADUser.GivenName, $ADUser.Surname, $ADUser.SamAccountName` otta work. finally, use `-join ';'` on the resulting collection.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be:

```
$result = '';
foreach ($user in cat C:\list.txt) {
  $adUser = Get-ADUser $user | select -Property GivenName,Surname,SamAccountName
  $result += [string]::Format("{0} {1} {2}; ", $adUser.GivenName, $adUser.Surname, $adUser.SamAccountName)
}
$result
```

Comment: similar ideas ... neatly done! i really enjoy seeing how differently one can do the same thing. [*grin*]

Comment: That works in principle, but it's worth noting that your output string will have a trailing `; ` sequence.

Answer (score 1):

A concise solution (PSv2+):

```
(Get-Content C:\list.txt | Get-ADUser | ForEach-Object {
  '{0} {1} {2}' -f $_.GivenName, $_.SurName, $_.SamAccountName
}) -join ';'
```

- `Get-Content C:\list.txt | Get-ADUser` uses the *pipeline* to provide the user names to `Get-ADUser` (which implicitly binds the input strings to its `-Identity` parameter); the result is an array of AD users objects.

  - Use of the pipeline vs. a `foreach` loop has trade-offs (memory consumption vs. speed); unless there is a known performance problem, however, the pipeline offers more concise, elegant solutions.
- Piping the result to the `ForEach-Object` (`%`) cmdlet allows processing the resulting AD user objects one by one, via a script block (`{ ... }`) in which `$_` represents the input object at hand.
- `'{0} {1} {2}' -f $_.GivenName, $_.SurName, $_.SamAccountName` uses `-f`, PowerShell's string-formatting operator, to build a string from the properties of the given user object. Note how there's no need for an intermediate `select` (`Select-Object`) call, given that you can access the properties of interest directly on the AD user object.
- Enclosing the entire pipeline in `(...)` results in an *array* of strings<sup>[1]</sup>, which `-join` then joins to form a single output string with `;` as the separator.

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, if `C:\list.txt` contained just *1* name, the output would be a *scalar*, i.e. a *single string*. However, the `-join` operator also accepts a scalar as the LHS, in which case the operation is a no-op (nothing to join).</sup>